# What is the word for 'repeating the tonic at the "end" of spelling a scale?'

Tags: scales, terminology

I am referring to the practice of repeating the root or tonic of a scale when spelling (not playing) a scale. I recall being told to *_*_ my scale but I cannot remember the word… at all.

Comment: Can you give an example of it written out on a staff? I think that would help me understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @ReinaAbolofia I think e.g. `A B C# D E F# G# (A)` -- saying that last A is `____ing` the scale.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe "completing" the scale?

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably call it *completing* or *finishing* or even *resolving* the scale. But I imagine the word you might have heard is *tagging* in the sense of *touching base*.